# Copy file from GCP to docker container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, circleci, gsutil

I have to copy file from gcp location to a specific directory in the docker image. I am using ubuntu:bionic as a parent image.

After installing Python and Pip, I tried following,

```
 RUN pip install gsutil \
   && gsutil cp gs:<some location> /home/${USER}/<some other location>
```

when I am building docker image, I am getting following error,

```
    13 19.84 /bin/sh: 1: gsutil: not found
```

Please let me know the mistake I am doing.

Comment: Can you share how did you installed Python and PIP?

Comment: Do you only want to use gsutil to download a file during your build? Do you use gsutil for anything else on that container?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for your issue depends on whether you need to use `gsutil` for other purposes inside your container or just to copy the file.

1. If you just need to copy the file with `gsutil`, it would be a good idea to use a [multi-stage build in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) so that your final container does not have extra tools installed (Cloud SDK in this case). This way it would be much lighter. The Dockerfile would be:

```docker
FROM google/cloud-sdk:latest
RUN gsutil cp <src_location> <intermediate_location>

FROM ubuntu:bionic
COPY --from=0 <intermediate_location> <dst_location>
```

2. If you need `gsutil` for further actions in your container, the Dockerfile to install it in ubuntu is the following:

```docker
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
    curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg  add - && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install google-cloud-sdk -y

RUN gsutil cp <src_location> <dst_location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bash inside the Docker container `docker exec -it (container name) bin/bash` and run each command one at a time, and if the command is successful, and then add to the dockerfile, this would help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks Shaqil. Can you please give me an example too.